# DS-160 application form

Tags: usa, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

Would you please provide information regarding occupation while filling DS-160. May I show two sources of income?  One is full time and second as freelancer?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have two sources of income, one full time and the second as a freelancer? Then that's what you write.